# How can I modify a list item after I created it with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my todo list what I made.
(To make my code more readable I tried to comment. I hope it worked.)

If you try my demo, you can add li items with the "add" button. And the li items has 2 more buttons.
I want to create a modify button to users with can modifying their list items. I have no idea what I can to do for this with jQuery.

Second problem is that list buttons don't work perfectly well. Because if I use once a delete button it change the done button to delete an item. But if I dont use the delete button, the done button is working well.
I dont know why, maybe the same class name is the problem?

Here is my demo in JS Bin:https://jsbin.com/natiziqawa/edit?html,js,output

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#add").click(function(){

 // Created list elements and their's buttons
    var list_item =document.createElement("li");
      var remove_button=document.createElement("button");
      var done_button=document.createElement("button");
     


 // append the buttons some string to caption buttons
   

   $(remove_button).append("Delete");
   $(done_button).append("Done");


   


 
 // added class name the items to to distinguish them 

  $(list_item).addClass("item")
  $(remove_button).addClass("delete"); 
  $(done_button).addClass("done"); 
  



 // filled  the created items with the input values
 
 var list_text =$("#input").val();
 var time=$("#time").val();
 
 
 // filled the list item with their's  buttons and class names and input values

 $(list_item).append(time,"   :   ",list_text,done_button,remove_button); 

 // finally fill the ul with list items but first check out what is written in the input


 if(input.value==""){
   alert("Please enter an activity")
 
  }


  // If the input has some value  can go 

  else{
 $("ul").append(list_item);

 // after clicked, clear the input field
 $("#input").val("");
 
  


// list item's buttons


$(".done").click(function(){

  $(list_item).click(function(){
    $(this).css("color","white")
    $(this).css("text-decoration","line-through")
  }); 
});





$(".delete").click(function(){
    $(list_item).click(function(){
      $(this).remove()
    }); 
  });

}

  });// main function close
  
}); // document ready close
```

Comment: Do you like jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind my solution is to use the `contenteditable` attribute for the added fields. To do this, you need to dynamically wrap the first two fields in an additional div, as shown here:

```
$(list_item).append('<div class="edit_item" contenteditable="true">'+time+'</div>',"   :   ",'<div class="edit_item" contenteditable="true">'+list_text+'</div>',done_button,remove_button);
```

You will need to replace this code with your existing one. For a better understanding, this code is located in the comment: **"// filled the list item with their's  buttons and class names and input values"**

Also, you need to add this rule to the css to align the fields:

```
.edit_item {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And regarding the second question:

You had a targeting problem. You must refer to the current `list_item` using the `closest()` method.

For mark:

```
$(".done").click(function(){
   $(this).closest(list_item).css("color","white")
   $(this).closest(list_item).css("text-decoration","line-through");
});
```

For removing:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
   $(this).closest(list_item).remove();
});
```

Comment: I tried your code and wow it's working. Thank you . 
I didn't know the contenteditable  before.

About my buttons, try it again, add 5 items and use once the delete button on the first element then use the done button on the last element. It's gonna be deleted.

Comment: @EndreKovács, Hello. Yes, there is such a problem. I updated my answer and gave you the code. It worked great for me.

Comment: Thank you very much is working. Can you tell me why didn't work code?

Comment: @EndreKovács, because you wrapped in two clicks on different selectors, making them parent-child - this is not correct.